# Simple Program Help - How To Display Multiple Lines of Text in JTextAreas From An Array List?

Tags: java, swing, text, netbeans, jtextarea

I'm trying to write a program that stores 5 song titles in an ArrayList "cdNames", and outputs them in a text area, one title per line, 5 lines total.

Im using the `.setText` method and a `for loop` to try to pull the 5 elements from the ArrayList to display the 5 song titles, without having to explicitly write each title out.

**What follows is the portion of my code that deals with the JTextArea:**

```
private void btnDisplayMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
for (int i = 0; i<cdNames.size();i++){
txtOutputBox.setText(cdNames.get(i));
```

The problem lies in that the only thing displayed in the text area is the last element in the array list.

Index # 4 i.e. The Rolling Stones - Gimme Shelter.

I believe the setText method is overwriting the previous elements and stopping at the last, instead of printing out each title on a new line.

I think my troubles lie in my insufficient knowledge of how text areas display text.

I'm new to java, so please try to answer my question simply if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use either append() or insert()  see [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29)

example (if your ArrayList has Strings)

```
for (String cdName: cdNames) {
    txtOutputBox.append(cdName);
}
```

Comment: I tried substituting the .setText method with the .append method, and although it did display all 5 elements (song titles), it seemed to have concatenated them into one huge line of text, as opposed to having one song title per line.
Any ideas on how I could separate the titles?

Comment: I found the solution.
The solution was to use "\n" to space the titles out.
Thank you so much, Nick Hol!